# Producing data for a cumulative distribution plot in bigquery

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery

I'd like to produce a cumulative plot that shows, for a given value, the percentage of data that is less than or equal to that value. In python / matplotlib / pandas, I can do this with the quantile function provided by pandas (and I guess numpy too):

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def plot_quantile(series, start=0., end=0.99):
    y = np.linspace(start,end, 500)
    x = series.quantile(y)
    plt.plot(x, y*100)
    plt.xlabel("Duration in minutes")
    plt.ylabel("% of drives less than x minutes") 
    plt.grid()
    
plot_quantile(df.duration)
```

In this case I'm plotting the distribution of taxi ride duration from [the NYC taxi dataset](https://www.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page).

[image]

I'd like to produce similar data with an SQL query to bigquery. I'm pretty close with the following query:

```
    select
        approx_quantiles(duration, 100) as duration_quantile
    from base_table
```

This gives me 101 data points, starting at the minimum value and ending at the max value. Now I have two problems:

- I have no idea how the values correspond to the quantile (e.g. which value is the P50?) - I'll need to generate those numbers too for the plot, as you see in the python code.
- I don't seem to have a way to truncate it near the top - as the max value is likely to be a very large outlier that makes my plot hard to read.

Comment: Hi @mChristos, for your requirement, I would suggest you to try by replacing the value 100 with 50 since it represents the number of quantiles to create which returns `number + 1`  points where the first element is approximate minimum and last element is approximate maximum. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, that doesn't help because like I mentioned, I don't want to include the maximum value - since it's likely to be an outlier. Rather I want to get a sense for the range where the bulk of my data sits, up to probably P95 or maybe P99. Beyond that, the scale will make it difficult to get much value from the plot.

Comment: for your first problem, `approx_quantiles(duration, 100)[OFFSET(50)]` isn't what you want for P50?

Comment: That's correct @Jaytiger - I can get the P50 that way. But I want a whole array of data, exactly the data sufficient to show the plot I've included in my question - so at least around 100 data points to get a decently smooth resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Below might not be what you want, but hope it helpful to you.

```sql
SELECT min,
       SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY min) cumulative_cnt,
       ROUND(SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY min) / SUM(cnt) OVER (), 4) cumulative_pct,
  FROM (
    -- trip count per duration in minutes
    SELECT ROUND(trip_seconds/60) min, COUNT(1) cnt,
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
     GROUP BY 1
  );
```

- I've used another dataset in the `bigquery-public-project` instead of *the NYC taxi dataset*.

Above query shows the cumulative distribution like below in Looker Studio.

[image]

> I don't seem to have a way to truncate it near the top - as the max value is likely to be a very large outlier that makes my plot hard to read.

Yes, it's not easy to read as you mentioned.

Looker Studio provides a custom filer. If you apply it to a chart, you can get a smoother curve.

[image]

[image]

Instead of filtering in Looker Studio, if you want it with a query, you can add `QUALIFY` condition at the bottom of the above query.

```sql
SELECT min,
       SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY min) cumulative_cnt,
       ROUND(SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY min) / SUM(cnt) OVER (), 4) cumulative_pct,
  FROM (
    SELECT ROUND(trip_seconds/60) min, COUNT(1) cnt,
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
     GROUP BY 1
  ) QUALIFY cumulative_pct < 0.99;
```